# Problems Batching Transactions with wXDAI in SAFE Gnosis

Tags: gnosis-safe, wrapped-tokens

I'm Trying to Send a Batched Transactions with Transaction Builder on Gnosis SAFE.
I'm trying to send different quantities of wXDAI to 8 different Address. Those Addresses are some of Owners of SAFE Wallet.

1. im using wxDAI contract token: [0xe91D153E0b41518A2Ce8Dd3D7944Fa863463a97d](https://gnosisscan.io/address/0xe91D153E0b41518A2Ce8Dd3D7944Fa863463a97d)
2. I'm Using "transfer" function as [Documentation suggested.](https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40841-transaction-builder)
3. I'm and adding decimals to wxDAI quantity. Example: 200 WxDAI = 200*10^18

After, following Steps suggested by [Documentation](https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40841-transaction-builder), the Tenderly Simulation it showed me up [this](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/57d586e5-632f-4c8a-9993-9ad345e867c1).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your Tenderly simulation and it seems you are trying to send more wxdai than you have in your Safe Account.

It is specifically the revert in the Tenderly Simulation, which happens inside the `transfer` call.

```
    require(balanceOf[src] >= wad);
```

Comment: so, i have to use decimals or not?
because documentation said use with decimals and decimals of wxDAI are 18..
200 wXDAI -> 200.000000000000000000 @schmanu

Comment: You have to use decimals. But the Safe you are sending the transaction from holds 0 wXDAI. That's why the simulation fails.